# Extension of bounded analytic functions from a countable subset to the whole unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f: \mathbb{D} \backslash \{0, 1/2, 1/3, \dots \}$be an analytic bounded function. Can $f$ be necessarily extended to an analytic function on $\mathbb{D}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First note that it has  a removable singularity at the points $\frac  1 2, \frac  1 3,...$. So we get an extension to $\mathbb D \setminus \{0\}$. Then extend to the whole of $\mathbb D$.

Comment: How do we know that the singularities are removable?

Comment: This is Riemann's Theorem. See 3) implies 1) in the theorem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity